# Method of characteristics PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I solved my PDE and got my charesteristic lines to by $y+\cos(x) =c$. The pde has boundary condition $u(0,y)=2y$ .

I know what the characteristic lines look like and I know that they fill the entire plane. But how could I argue this using my graph that $u(x,y)$ leads to a solution at all points in the $X-Y$ plane.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an equation of the form $a\,u_x+b\,u_y=0$, the general solution will be $u=\phi(y-\cos x)$. From $u(0,y)=\phi(y-1)=2\,y$ we get $\phi(y)=2(y+1)$ and
$$
u(x,y)=2(y-\cos x+1).
$$

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for answering, however I have 2 questions suppose $u(x,y) =2(y-ln(x)+1)$ that would mean the u(x,y) isn't defined at all points? Also am I correct that there is no other solution to the pde since it covers the X-Y because of uniqueness(Maximum Principe Theorem).

Comment: If the solution  were that, tren it would be defined only for $x>0$. Without knowing the equation it is dificult to say anything.